# Prove that quadratic polynomial attains a minimum

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, polynomials, optimization

I would like to prove:

Let $p(z) = z^2 +az +b$, where a and b are positive, and $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that $|p(z)|$ attains minimum over the region $\Re(z)) \geq 0$ on the imaginary axis.

Here is what I have done:

By contradiction, suppose that |p(z)| does not attain its minimum on $\Re(z)) \geq 0$. So then, it must be that $|p(z)| = c$, some constant. Or we get that $|p(z)|^2 = c^2$. Taking partial derivatives, we get that $\frac{\partial |p(z)|^2}{\partial x}$ = $\frac{\partial |p(z)|^2}{\partial y}$ = $0$.

If $p(z)$ is as defined above, then we can of course separate into real and imaginary parts $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$. Thus, we get:
$\frac{\partial |p(z)|^2}{\partial x}$ = $2uu_x + 2vv_x = 0$.Similarly, we get $\frac{\partial |p(z)|^2}{\partial y}$ = $2uu_y + 2vv_y = 0$.Since $p(z)$ is entire and hence analytic, we can exploit the fact that Cauchy Riemman equations hold. So the equations become $uu_x -vu_y =0$ and $uu_y + vv_y = 0$. After multiplying the first by u and second by 2 and combining we get: $(u^2 + v^2)(u_x + u_x) = 0$. Since $c^2 = u^2 + v^2$, then $c^2(u_x + u_x) =0$. Similarly, multiplying first equation by v and second by u, and applying CR, then $(u^2 +v^2)v_x = c^2v_x = 0$, and so $v_x =0$.Again, using CR, we get that $v_x= -u_y= u_x=v_y=0$ by what we get above.So $p'(z) = 0$ and so $p(z) = const$, but that's a contradiction, since $p'(z) = 2z+a$.

I am not sure whether my logic here is right, especially at the beginning when stating that if |f| does not achieve a minimum, then |f| is constant.Can someone please verify?

Comment: In fact the opposite is true, if $|f|$ does not achieve its minimum, it cannot be constant, because constant functions achieve their unique minimum(and maximum)

Comment: Ok, I see the flaw. Is then going by contradiction the best way to prove this then?

Comment: I haven't tried so I don't know. What I do know however is that a proof by contradiction should start with "suppose $|f|$ does not achieve its minimum over $\Re z\ge 0$ $\color{green}{\text{on the imaginary line}}$"

Comment: In addition a quadratic is a relatively simple beast, so I'm guessing a direct proof is possible (expand $p(z) = a(x+iy) + i b(x+iy) $ for real valued functions $a,b$ and see what happens)

Comment: So if we went with contradiction still, I think we can say , including the on the imaginary line statement, then that, if |f| does not achieve its minimum over said region, then looking at $\Re(z) >0$, then if we had a solution, then as $|p(z)| > 0$, we get that $p'(z) = 0$. But, $p'(z) = 2z +a$ has no zero in $\Re(z) >0$. Is that a bit better?

Comment: Also, I overlooked the fact that since a, b are positive-then all the roots will lie in the open left half plane.

Comment: Why does $|p(z)|>0$ imply $p'(z)=0$? If you are trying to apply the first derivative test, note that it is $|p(z)|$ and not $p(z)$ that has a minimum (and |p(z)|^2 isn't complex analytic)